# Android different options menu for different adapters

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a listView called contactsView and im setting adapters so the listview displays contacts and groups.

In the onCreate method I have:

```
contactsView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter)
```

Then I have a groups button with a listener and in the onClick of that button I have:

```
contactsView.setAdapter(groupsAdapter)
```

Now my options menu code looks like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println(contactsView.getAdapter());
        if (contactsView.getAdapter().equals(contactsAdapter)){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts_options_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }else if (contactsView.getAdapter().equals(groupsAdapter)){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.groups_options_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

However it is not working and I dont understand why, any idea? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found this...

Android only calls onCreateOptionsMenu ONCE to create the inital options menu. If you want to change the options menu at runtime - you must implement onPrepareOptionsMenu which will get called when you call invalidateOptionsMenu().